# Adding Entity object with foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In database I have 2 tables:
Article: ID | Title| SectionID
Section: ID | SectionName
(all ids set as Identity Increment)

I want to add new Article with specific SectionID  (that exits in database).

I tired this:

```
Article art = new Article
{
    Title = "title"
};

art.Section.SectionID = 0;


if (art.EntityState == EntityState.Detached)
{
   Articlerctx.AddToArticles(art);
}
```

I get error on  art.Section.SectionID = 0;

> Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object

Do I need to create a complete object just for one int field???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can of course get the object from the database (I didn't see the "exists in database", sorry).

just grab the `Section` object from your context and assign it.

```
art.Section = context.Section.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ID == 0);
```

Comment: Anyway  it says that Linq to entities doesn't support SingleOrDefault and FirstOrDefault should be used.

Comment: Yup, you are right with the method. With the performance: I didn't feel it in my project at least. Also, you have the advantage of the object being strongly typed, which reduces error potential if you'd construct the entity key yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
art.SectionReference.EntityKey = new EntityKey("EntityModelName.EntitySetName", "IdFieldName", 0);
```

Comment: I realize the example in the question isn't using POCO, but I think it is worth noting that this will not work with POCO.

Comment: If the Section ids are TRULY well-known, and are not going to change any time soon, I do this pattern with an enum, e.g. (int)SectionId.Introduction. That reduces magic numbers and improves clarity. But don't do this if the sections can be modified in your application.

Comment: I don't like this becase of weak-type

Comment: Yep. There's a trade-off between type safety and not having the db round trip. By the way, the first argument should be something more like "EntityModelName.EntitySetName", e.g., "MyEntityModel.Customers". At any rate, you've got two solutions you can choose between now - mine for performance, and the other for type safety. Frankly, I would choose the type safety unless testing reveals a performance problem.

Comment: About the first Argument you right, for 15 minutes I didn't understand why it didn't accept object that encapsulates (?) the Model... it only accepts model as it is.

Answer (score 0):

In EF 4 you can check the box on the update model wizard to include foreign key fields in the model. If you do this, you can then change your code to:

```
Article art = new Article
{
    Title = "title"
};

art.SectionID = 0;

if (art.EntityState == EntityState.Detached)
{
   Articlerctx.AddToArticles(art);
}
```